# How to retrieve a sub query in prisma client with same table?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma, prisma-graphql

```
select * 
from WeeklyChallengeCourses 
where weekly_challenge_id = (select weekly_challenge_id 
                             from WeeklyChallengeCourses 
                             where course_id = 210);
```

Result will be the below selected one:

[image]

```
const data = await context.prisma.weeklyChallengeCourses.findMany({
        where:{
            weekly_challenge_id: {
                ..............
            }
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

In Prisma, you would have to use two *different* queries to solve this:

1. Run an equivalent of the subquery to fetch the `weekly_challenge_id`
2. Run a `findMany` with the `weekly_challenge_id` found in step 1.

```js
// I'm assuming course_id is unique. 
const course = await context.prisma.findUnique({ where: { course_id: 210 } }); 

const data = await context.prisma.weeklyChallengeCourses.findMany({
        where:{
            weekly_challenge_id: course.weekly_challenge_id
        },
    });
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`rawQuery` feature](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access)  to run the SQL directly and do it in one query.

Comment: Is it the only option other than raw Query?

Comment: I don't think there's a single prisma query that can do this for you, unfortunately. I can't speak definitively, but nothing else comes to mind.

Comment: thanks for information shared  @Tasin Ishmam

Comment: Welcome, hope I could help :)